# Zend Framework / Form / DisplayGroup / SetLegend problem

Tags: forms, zend-framework, legend, fieldset

I have the following code in my 'Default_Form_Registration' class (inside _init method):

```
$fullname = $this->addDisplayGroup(
                       array('firstname', 'lastname'),
                       'fullname');
$fullname->setLegend('Full Name');
```

My form is being displayed properly (elements inside the fieldset), however there is no legend being displayed.  I have not changed the decorators at all, using default decorators.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass options to the `addDisplayGroup` through the 3rd param:

```
 $fullname = $this->addDisplayGroup(
                   array('firstname', 'lastname'),
                   'fullname', array('legend' => 'Full Name'));
```

Also, as a note, `addDisplayGroup` returns `Zend_Form` and not the display group.

If you want to use the `setLegend` method, you need to do like this:

```
 $this->getDisplayGroup('fullname')->setLegend('Full Name');
```

Comment: meh, I thought I tried that, apparently not, that worked (the third parameter array('legend' => 'Full Name') fixed the problem.  Thanks +1